# Library for html form design gui

Tags: javascript, html, gui, user-interface, forms

I am looking for a (javascript/jquery?) based library for a webinterface that lets users design forms.

I'm going to build an application for scientific data entry, where users can design the data entry form for their dataset.

The use case is a lead scientist who designs a form for the data entry for their scientific project. Other team members can then use that form to enter the data they have collected.

Of course data storage and handling will be handled in the back-end. What I am looking for now is for the front-end where I need a library that let's the lead scientist add fields to a form, name them and then when they're done, the form is saved in a format (html sound logical but others are fine as well) so the form can then be stored (in the back-end) and be rendered for data collectors to enter their data.

The whole system will be a webapplication, possibly python based, but I'd prefer to separate the interface from the back-end, so a pure html/javascript library/framework would be preferred.

I am quite familiar with jquery and to a lesser extent extjs (sencha), so extensions on top of that would be nice, but other libraries or frameworks are welcome as well.